# ExpressJS Socket hang up after mongoose-ttl or basic MongoDB TTL reaps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm coding up a Node.js server using ExpressJS and MongoDB with MongooseJS.

I have a collection called `measurements`. I want every document in this collection to be contained in the DB only for 24 hours. Every document that is older than 24 hours should be deleted.

To achieve this goal I've used both npm's `mongoose-ttl` package and MongoDB's built-in TTL.

The code for `mongoose-ttl` case:

```
const ttl = require('mongoose-ttl');

const weatherMeasurementsSchema = Schema({
    parentRoomId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Room" },
    temperature: Number,
    humidity: Number,
    createdAt: Date
});

weatherMeasurementsSchema.plugin(ttl, { ttl: "1m", interval: "1m" });
```

The code for pure MongoDB case:

```
 db.measurements.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 60})
```

For testing purposes I set the `ttl` and `interval` fields to 1 minute only, so I can gather the results earlier.

Both `mongoose-ttl` and MongoDB's TTL delete the data properly, but after they do that, my server crashes with error: `Error: socket hang up`

What could be the cause of this?

EDIT:

I investigated this further, and the only thing more that I have come upon is that the error is thrown after querying to the DB for that collection.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156132/mongoerror-socket-hang-up

Comment: @Saravana I edited the post, because I found some new information. Please check the `edit` section. Does that change anything?

Comment: @Saravana Im sorry but I dont use neither `mongojs` nor `ssl` connection